# interpreting HTML tags

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using ASP Classic, I have a column with tags HTML:

Example:

`select column1 from table1` ⇒ `"<b>test</b>"`

I want to retrieve the value of this column in my page asp, to interpret the tag bold in display page.

Example:

```
<div> <%= column1 %></div>
```

desired result

In page display we want to have a text with bold style ⇒ **test**

Comment: You're retrieving the text `<b>test</b>` from a database and you want to write that to your page so that it displays **test**?

Comment: So, what doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aimar:

Try this copy+paste where you are currently seeing unexpected results and see if anything stands out:

```
<% Response.Write "<b>test</b>" & "  " & rs("column1") %>
<% Response.Write "<b>test</b>" & "  " & chr(34) & rs("column1") & chr(34) %>
```

Comment: ok its work, i have a function who denied the html to interpret